# Interfaces y Clases en Java

Tags: java

Mí problema es el siguiente:
Una `InterestCheckingAccount` es una `Account` que también es una `InterestBearingAccount`.

Y lo que no entiendo es como crear `InterestCheckingAccount`,  porque `Account` es una Clase y `InterestBearingAccount` es un interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías ser más claro con tus preguntas. No obstante, conforme lo planteas deberás crear la clase InterestCheckingAccount que extienda de Account e implemente InterestBearingAccount.

Quedaría algo parecido a esto:

```
public class InterestCheckingAccount extends Account implements InterestBearingAccount {}
```

Para ello, obviamente, la clase Account deberá ser una clase **abstracta**. De todas formas, si esto no te cuadra tal vez tu problema venga dado a que tu proyecto necesite reestructurar la arquitectura de clases y enfocar la POO de tu proyecto de otra forma.

Comment: El problema planteado es para un trabajo de la Universidad, y mí duda era como pasar esa condición a la syntaxis de Java.
Tú aporte me sirvió muchisimo. Gracias!.